# What is an alternative to a BAT file on Mac?

Tags: macos, filesystem, script, file

What is the alternate for BAT file (Windows) on Mac? Does different version of OS X have different format of BAT files? I am trying to create a BAT file on Mac which normally changes directory while the file is open.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589905/equivalent-of-double-clickable-sh-and-bat-on-mac) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065069/equivalent-of-bat-in-mac-os)

Comment: Look at Unix shell scripts or python, perl or other scripting languages

Comment: Let's focus on general ways to do things similar to BAT files in this question. If you need help in getting a specific problem solved please ask a new question.

Answer (score 9):

Being pretty unfamiliar with batch files, I'm not sure of the functionality available, but there are two main scripting methods on OS X which are similar:

- ### AppleScript

  AppleScript is a scripting language which lets you control OS X and many applications.

  AppleScripts are generally easy to understand and write whilst providing a lot of advanced functionality. Here is an AppleScript which counts the files in the Applications folder:

  ```
  tell application "Finder"
      if folder "Applications" of startup disk exists then
          return count files in folder "Applications" of startup disk
      else
          return 0
      end if
  end tell
  ```

  For more information about AppleScript, see:

  - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html
- ### Shell script

  A shell script is a script for a Unix shell.

  The equivalent shell script to the above AppleScript is the following:

  ```
  if [ -d "/Applications/" ]; then
      ls -1 "/Applications/" | wc -l
  fi
  ```

  As you're probably going to use bash, this is a good guide to get you started:

  - http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Answer (score -1):

Look up .bash or .command on mac ;)